# Change WPF Label content while program is loading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a WPF application that loads a lot of content and UI updates in the same code blocks, and I want to show the progress or what task is doing in the `Label.Content` property, currently I'm doing this:

```
void LoadEverything()
{
    UpdateContentLabel("Loading items");
    foreach(string i in stringArrayItems)
    {
         UpdateContentLabel("Loading " + i + " info...");
         //LoadTasks
    }

    UpdateContentLabel("Loading history");
}

void UpdateContentLabel(string Task)
{
    myLoadLabel.Content = Task;
}
```

The first problem is that label content is not updated, I'm aware that UI Thread and the task thread are the same and that's why UI freezes, I tried to use `BackgroundWorker` to put the load tasks on it and `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { /*UI Updates */ });` the UI updates (like create custom `ListBoxItem` and add it to a `ListBox`) and throws a `TargetInvocationException` in `app.ShowDialog();` (`app` is not the first form, is the `mainApp` dialog and is created in a login window).

```
BackgroundWorker loadInfo = new BackgroundWorker();

private void app_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    loadInfo.DoWork += loadInfo_DoWork;
    loadInfo.RunWorkerCompleted += loadInfo_RunWorkerCompleted;
    loadInfo.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    loadInfo.RunWorkerAsync();
}
public void loadInfo_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateContentLabel("Load complete :)");
}

public void loadInfo_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { UpdateContentLabel("Loading items"); });
    foreach(string i in stringArrayItems)
    {
         this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { UpdateContentLabel("Loading " + i + " info..."); });
         //LoadTasks
         this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { /*UI Updates */ });
    }
}
```

So, the question is what can I do to show the current task in the label aforementioned?

Edit:
Project versión of .NET is 3.5.

Comment: Are you using an MVVM pattern? Any other frameworks you're using?

Comment: @Noctis No, I'm not using MVVM or other frameworks, the version of .NET I'm using is 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Put your logic inside the `foreach` loop, not inside a second `BeginInvoke`.

Here's a running functional example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker loadInfo = new BackgroundWorker();

    private List<string> stringArrayItems = new List<string>{
        "First file",
        "second file",
        "third file ",
        "fourth file "
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        loadInfo.DoWork += loadInfo_DoWork;
        loadInfo.RunWorkerCompleted += loadInfo_RunWorkerCompleted;
        loadInfo.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        loadInfo.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public void loadInfo_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateContentLabel("Load complete :)");
    }

    public void loadInfo_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => UpdateContentLabel("Loading items")));
        foreach (string i in stringArrayItems)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                UpdateContentLabel("Loading " + i + " info...")
            ));

            //LoadTasks
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Loading {0} and sleeping for a second.", i);
        }
    }

    void UpdateContentLabel(string Task)
    {
        MyLabel.Content = Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I have a doubt, in `//LoadTasks` there are UI Updates such as `lbItems.Items.Add(i);` or `if (lbItems.Items.Count <= 0) { lNoItems.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; }` and throws `InvalidOperationException`, where can I move these UI updates and stay synchronized within the tasks. Sorry for not include that in the question.

Comment: @SteelersMan **First**: update your question then. **Second**: I'd move all of the UI things to a method, and use the `BeginInvoke` there. Kind of hard to say without more specifics. **Third**: I don't know if MVVM is an option, but the binding and flexibility it'll give you, will make all this GUI updates much easier (on the down side, a rather steep learning curve if you never played with it before).

Comment: I tried to make the most easy to read to anyone who reads this question, specially in the code, that's why I accidentally ignored some info, in my code there's a lot of mixed UI operations (such as visibility property, add listboxitems, load custom controls), I/O and resource management (byte arrays, BitmapImage, etc.) and I tried to separate some of them but I didn't get the results I expected (exceptions everywhere).

Comment: sounds like your code is in need of some good old style refactoring and cleaning then ...

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have created sample code to match your code scenario. Here, idea is not accessing the UI element directly from code behind (in your case that is ListBox). By using INotifyPropertyChanged you can utilize the List collection to bind to your ListBox's ItemsSource and update the bound collection on code behind that eliminate your UI thread attachment requirement. So here you go:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableListItems}">
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged section
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private List<int> availableListItems;
    public List<int> AvailableListItems
    {
        get
        {
            return availableListItems;
        }
        set
        {
            availableListItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AvailableListItems");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AvailableListItems = new List<int>();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    BackgroundWorker loadInfo = new BackgroundWorker();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        loadInfo.DoWork += loadInfo_DoWork;
        loadInfo.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        loadInfo.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public void loadInfo_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            AvailableListItems.Add(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            OnPropertyChanged("OnPropertyChanged");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope, this will be helpful.

Comment: He's not using MVVM, so I doubt binding and INPC will be what he wants to go with...